# MFCC: What are the frequency ranges of the 20 filter banks in Librosa MFCC?

Tags: frequency, speech, mfcc, librosa

In Librosa library, When we use librosa.feature.mfcc(y, sr), it returns a (20, ?) numpy array.
How do I check the frequency range of the 20 filter-banks that are returned?

Answer (score 0):

MFCC does not return filterbank values, it transforms them with DCT, so you do not have frequency range for every value, it is more an abstract coefficient.

If you want to print filterbank frequencies during MFCC calculation you can easily use debugger or additional print statements inside librosa code, it is scripting language, so you will see the result right away.